# Type 'Observable<IAgency[]>' is not assignable to type 'IAgency[]'

Tags: angular

Am using angular material to create a data table. when i bind the data-source i am getting error. Using angular 5 and angular material design

**ManageAgencysComponent .ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DistrictService } from '../../services/district.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class ManageAgencysComponent implements OnInit {

  columnsToDisplay=['name','Date','IsDeleted'];
  dataSource= new MatTableDataSource<IAgency>();
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private districtService: DistrictService,
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.data= this.districtService.getAgencyList(false);
  }
```

**DistrictService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {  Response } from '@angular/http';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import { IAgency } from '../interfaces/IAgency';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DistrictService {

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
    private _config: ConfigService
  ) { }
    getAgencyList(isDeleted: boolean): Observable<IAgency[]> {
          const url = this._config.getAgencyListURL(isDeleted);
          return this._http.get<IAgency[]>(url);
        }
```

**IAgency interface**

```
export interface IAgency {
    agencyId: number;
    agencyName: string;
    changeDateStamp: string;
    isDeleted: boolean;
}

export class Agency implements IAgency {
    constructor(
        public agencyId: number = 0,
        public agencyName: string = '',
        public changeDateStamp: string = '',
        public isDeleted: boolean = false
     ) {}
}
```

**Error**

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'IAgency[]'. 
>   Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all.

You're trying to assign Type `'Observable'` which will be returned by the `getAgencyList` method, to type `'IAgency[]'` which is expected by the `MatTableDataSource`

Change your current implementation to this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DistrictService } from '../../services/district.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class ManageAgencysComponent implements OnInit {

  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'Date', 'IsDeleted'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource < IAgency > ();
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private districtService: DistrictService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.districtService.getAgencyList(false)
      .subscribe(result => this.dataSource.data = result);
  }
}
```